# Marshalling Joda LocalTime in Grails

Tags: json, grails, groovy, jodatime

I am trying to marshall an object that contains LocalTime joda type time. And the problem occurs if you try to return a time that is later than 12am, so in the example below if the start of a lesson is 14:00 (2pm) then the time is converted to 02:00 and not 14:00 in the specified format (hh:mm).

So my BootStrap.groovy file contains following code:

```
   JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Lesson) {
    def returnArray = [:]
    returnArray['start'] = it.start.toString("hh:mm")
    return returnArray
   }
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  to get a 24 hrs format you need HH:mm,  that's why you get 02:00 instead of 14:00

Comment: Thanks - that was so obvious :)

Comment: Could you please close the question? Thanks